# Making sure the data is flushed when closing the serial connection on mac

Tags: python, macos, serial-port

I am trying to interface an Agilent 54622D oscilloscope on Mac OS and I am using an ftdi usb-serial cable. I am observing the following behavior: if I close a serial connection's file descriptor immediately after the write command (I don't expect any response from the device, just sending a command), the connection will be closed immediately which results in not all data sent to the device. This seems somewhat logical, but I have never seen anyone adding any kind of special delays before closing a serial connection.

What could I be missing here?

Here is a simple python script to illustrate the issue:

```
import serial
port=serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbserial-A603PQBN",baudrate=57600,timeout=1, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=False, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
port.write(":RUN\n")
port.close()
```

**Update:**

I have tried the same script in VirtualBox running Linux and I didn't notice any problems like these whatsoever. Now I wonder wether this is Mac's UART driver or an FTDI driver issues.

Comment: Almost certainly an OSX builtin FTDI driver issue, 9 years later this is still an issue, see: https://github.com/serialport/serialport-rs/issues/117#issuecomment-1667409332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried official FTDI drivers and the issue went away. This could be a bug in Mavericks FTDI driver implementation (filed a bug).

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you close the connection sooner, then are data really processed, even though your connection speed is rather high (I am used to 9600).

So why not trying to use `flush()` which is in doc described:

"Flush of file like objects. In this case, wait until all data is written."

```
import serial
port=serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbserial-A603PQBN",baudrate=57600,timeout=1, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=False, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
port.write(":RUN\n")
port.flush() # this might help
port.close()
```

Comment: I tried doing both flush and flushInput and that doesn't seem to help. It almost looks like closing the connection just interrupts the transfer immediately.

Comment: @dgdmitry Thanks for sharing this experience, I am using serial sometime too. I will ask my colleague who is HW and C expert, this sounds really strange.

Comment: Thanks! I want to test this behavior in linux as well, I suspect the difference might be in UART drivers in Mac, although it should be posix compliant.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't reproduce with linux in a virtual box on the very same machine. Sigh.